# Firefox: make "file://path/to/a/directory/" open Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, firefox

Is there a way to make FireFox open a Windows Explorer view of the directory when clicking a hyperlink with a href that begins with `file://` and specifically points to a directory, not a file (perhaps even only when it expicitly does so by ending with a trailing delimiter `/`?)

Ideally it would do as prescribed under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open\command` (I see now there's something else there under newer Windows versions than what I remember from XP...), but there's [a Shell API call for that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx)...

Is this possible with changes to `about:config`? Is it possible with an add-on? Should I post this as a feature request on bugzilla?

Comment: Similar (pretty old) question, maybe it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804604/firefox-open-local-link-to-directory-with-explorer